# How to extract number plate of white colored vehicle

Tags: matlab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [segment digits in an image - Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545020/segment-digits-in-an-image-matlab)

I am working on vehicle number plate recognition system using MATLAB. I tried extracting the number plate using threshold and mathematical morphology, but i'm getting problems while extracting the plate area when the vehicle is white colored. I searched the web but most of them were using edge detection. Can anyone help me out to extract number plate without using edge detection?

Comment: I think that a good start is OpenCV. A related question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227074/horizontal-line-detection-with-opencv

Comment: Have you looked at [stroke width transform](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/149305/1509.pdf)?

Comment: It might help if you showed the sort of images which are giving you a problem.

Comment: As you can see, the answers you are getting are not too informative and quite brief. The reason for this is your question: it is also too short and too brief and does not show any effort on your part. Please ask a [good question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) so we can give you better answers!